# Do Unicode strings in Python 3 still depend on "narrow" / "wide" builds?

Tags: python, unicode, python-3.x

Since Python 2.2 and [PEP 261](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0261/), Python can be built in "narrow" or "wide" mode, which affects the definition of a "character", i.e. "the addressable unit of a Python Unicode string".

Characters in narrow builds look like UTF-16 code units:

```
>>> a = u'\N{MAHJONG TILE GREEN DRAGON}'
>>> a
u'\U0001f005'
>>> len(a)
2
>>> a[0], a[1]
(u'\ud83c', u'\udc05')
>>> [hex(ord(c)) for c in a.encode('utf-16be')]
['0xd8', '0x3c', '0xdc', '0x5']
```

*(The above seems to disagree with [some](http://www.cmlenz.net/archives/2008/07/the-truth-about-unicode-in-python) [sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838170/what-is-internal-representation-of-string-in-python-3-x) that insist that narrow builds use UCS-2, not UTF-16. Very intriguing indeed)*

Does Python 3.0 keep this distinction? Or are all Python 3 builds wide?

(I've heard about [PEP 393](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/) that changes internal representation of strings in 3.3, but this doesn't relate to 3.0 ~ 3.2.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, from 3.0 to 3.2 they do. Windows uses narrow builds while (most) Unix uses wide builds

Using Python 3.2 on Windows:

```
>>> a = '\N{MAHJONG TILE GREEN DRAGON}'
>>> len(a)
2
>>> a
''
```

While this behavior is expected on 3.3+ using Windows:

```
>>> a = '\N{MAHJONG TILE GREEN DRAGON}'
>>> len(a)
1
>>> a
'\U0001f005'
>>> print(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    print(a)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode character '\U0001f005' 
in position 0: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk
```

The UCS-2 codec is used on Tk (I'm using IDLE - the terminal may show another error).

Comment: I made a couple tests on what platforms are using which build. Narrow: Windows, Mac, NetBSD, OpenBSD, Solaris. Wide: Linux, FreeBSD. Tested with Python 2.7. So I can't say most Unix* use wide builds.

Comment: @jonnyJD: For Python 2.7, correct. The statement above was for 3.0 to 3.2.